# Logic Apps - XML Transform - Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited?

Tags: xml, azure, xslt, azure-logic-apps

I have an XSLT 1.0 map for an XML transformation action in an Azure Logic App.

The XSLT template code this:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="some.uri" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="status">
    <xsl:value-of select="job/status"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="feedback">
    <xsl:value-of select="job/custom_fields/custom_field[name = 'Work Feedback Reason']/value"/>
</xsl:variable>


    <!-- Set mapping table  -->
        <my:map>
            <entry key="Incorrect">Missing Item</entry> 
            <entry key="Damaged">Damaged Item</entry> 
            <entry key="Defective">Defective Item</entry> 

        </my:map>
<xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$status = 'canceled'">
                    <feedback>
                        <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/my:map/entry[@key=$feedback]"/>
                        <!-- <xsl:copy-of select="$feedbackReason"></xsl:copy-of> -->
                    </feedback>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to run this in a XML transformation action, I get an error:

```
"body": {
    "Code": "InvalidXsltContent",
    "Message": "An error occurred while processing map. 'Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it. An error occurred at (51,25).'",
    "Details": null,
    "InnerError": null
```

Any ideas how I set XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction in the logic app XML transform action?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're not using document() properly.  It's purpose is to load external Xml for use in the current transform.

While document('') is supposed to load the current document, this shouldn't be necessary.  Have you tried just using .?

Comment: `document('')` refers to the root node of the stylesheet. This allows the OP to access `my:map` in the stylesheet itself. From what I can tell (tested with Xalan and two versions of Saxon) the OP is using `document()` properly.